# Javascript function with for loop, prompt ask user how many numbers, the number of prompts shows up if its letter or word it has return "wrong"

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I am brand new with javascript and I have a problem that i can't figure out.

My first prompt ask the user how many numbers he wants to give in. If he give in "3" then 3 prompts shows up to ask him to put a random number he wants.

if there is no number but a letter or word it should show "wrong" cancelled or don't wrote anything.

```js
        function controleAantal(aantal) {
        if ( aantal === " ") {
            return "U heeft niks ingegeven" // user didn't wrote anything
        }

        else if(aantal == null){
            return "Uw hebt geannuleerd" // user cancelled
        }

        else if( aantal > 0) {
            return aantal // display number that user has given
        }

        else {
            return "Dit is geen correcte ingave " + 0 // This is not correct number
        }
    }
    

        let vragen = Number(prompt("Hoeveel getallen wilt uw ingeven?"));

        let getallen = [];
        let vraag2 = controleAantal(getallen)

        for (let i = 0; i < vragen; i++) {
        getallen.push(Number(prompt(`Geef in jouw nummer ${i + 1} in.`)));



        document.write(`<p> ${vraag2[i]}</p>`);
        }
```

Comment: OK, so that's what you want. But what's your problem? What's your question to us?

Comment: It shows as result this 
"
D

i

t
"
It should show as result (first prompt user write letter it should return "wrong") When the user gives in a nummber it should return the number. And that is not happening.

Comment: It is because you do `controleAantal(getallen)` and `getallen`is [] so the return is `"Dit is geen correcte ingave " + 0`.

Then in the loop you write `<p>${vraag2[i]}</p>`. So if you wanted 3 `getallen`it will output `D i t` as it is the 3 first letters of the sentence returned

Answer (score 1):

There are quite some issues with your code. You mix up several variables and should not use a mixed return value, since then you cannot distinguish between error case or normal case. You may want to try the solution below. Also consider to check the input of your actual numbers in the loop with a somewhat similar approach.

```js
function controleAantal(aantal) {
  if(aantal === null) { // no input
    return { error: "Uw hebt geannuleerd" } // user cancelled
  }
  else if ( !aantal.trim().length ) { // trimmed string is empty
    return { error: "U heeft niks ingegeven" } // user didn't wrote anything
  }
  else if( +aantal > 0) { // casted number is greater than 0
    return { aantal } // display number that user has given
  }
  else {
    return { error: "Dit is geen correcte ingave" } // This is not correct number
  }
}
    

let vragen = prompt("Hoeveel getallen wilt uw ingeven?");
let vraag2 = controleAantal(vragen)

if (vraag2.error) {
  document.write(`<p> ${vraag2.error} </p>`)
} else {
  let getallen = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < vraag2.aantal; i++) {
    getallen.push(Number(prompt(`Geef in jouw nummer ${i + 1} in.`)));

    document.write(`<p> ${getallen[i]}</p>`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function controleAantal(aantal) {
    if ( aantal === "") {
      return "U heeft niks ingegeven" // user didn't wrote anything
    }

    else if(aantal == null){
      return "Uw hebt geannuleerd" // user cancelled
    }

    else if( aantal > 0) {
      return aantal // display number that user has given
    }

    else {
      return "Dit is geen correcte ingave " + 0 // This is not correct number
    }
  }


  let input1 = prompt("Hoeveel getallen wilt uw ingeven?");
  let vragen = Number(input1);
    console.log(`input 1 [${input1}], number ${vragen}`, input1)
  if (isNaN(vragen) || vragen<1) {
    document.write(`<p> input1 : [${input1}], translated text [${controleAantal(input1)}]</p>`);
  } else {

    // let vraag2 = controleAantal(getallen)

    for (let i = 0; i < vragen; i++) {
      // getallen.push(Number(prompt(`Geef in jouw nummer ${i + 1} in.`)));
      let input = prompt(`Geef in jouw nummer ${i + 1} in.`);


      // document.write(`<p> ${vraag2[i]}</p>`);
      document.write(`<p> ${i} : input[${input}] tranlated text ${controleAantal(input)}</p>`);
    }
  }
```

The problem is caused by `Number(x)`, it will return 0 if x is blank string('' or ' ' with any length).

Use `isNaN()` to check number, `NaN` stands for Not a Number.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome @kenny to SO.

There are several solutions to your issue but I would give you the simple one that fits your code.

1. Your function accepted the `primitive` parameter `aantal` which can be :

   - string ( empty )
   - null
   - number
2. You call that function with an `array` variable named `gettalen` !
   !
3. Your checks `if/else` expressions are against a `primitive` variable not an `array`
4. The expected result whatever your input is `NaN` :

   `` (Number(prompt(`Geef in jouw nummer ${i + 1} in.`))) ``

   So your function returns the last check `Dit is geen correcte ingave`
5. If I `iterate 3 times` I get `D i t`.

You should ask GOOGLE:

1. How to check against empty value?
2. How to check against a number value?
3. How to check against a null value?

#### The solution

```js
function controleAantal(aantal) {
  if (aantal === '') {
    return 'U heeft niks ingegeven'; // user didn't wrote anything
  }
  if (aantal === null) {
    return 'Uw hebt geannuleerd'; // user cancelled
  }
  if (!Number.isNaN(aantal) && aantal > 0) {
    return aantal; // display number that user has given
  }
  return 'Dit is geen correcte ingave '; // This is not correct number
}

let vragen = Number(prompt('Hoeveel getallen wilt uw ingeven?'));

let getallen = [];

for (let i = 0; i < vragen; i++) {
  const value = prompt(`Geef in jouw nummer ${i + 1} in.`);
  const controlled = controleAantal(value);
  getallen.push(controlled);
  document.write(`<p> ${getallen[i]}</p>`);
}
```